# Google Analytics with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-analytics, spark-streaming

I have a requirement to pull the data from Google Analytics which needs to be processed by Spark and save the output to Cassandra. I read multiple articles related to this topic and found GitHub link related to Spark and GA.

```
https://github.com/crealytics/spark-google-analytics
```

The link is quite useful. I have also created a GA account for this. But in the implementation, I am unable to find some of the options values like-**refreshToken,clientSecret,etc**. I tried to retrieve the above stated options via GA developer API but not seeing any values.

If anyone has implemented the same, please assist me on this.

Answer (score 1):

To get the clientSecret and refreshToken you will need to create a new project in Google Cloud Platform and enable the GA API for that project. You can then get these tokens following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).